# Step Functions: How to share context between Lambdas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, aws-step-functions

I have a data processing workflow like this. The Download task creates a session ID (GUID) and pass it to Parse task and then the Post task. If any exception occurs in these three tasks, the workflow jumps to Failed task. The  Failed task would update the status of the process as failed in DynamoDB. To do that, it needs to get the session ID.

Is there any way to pass the session ID to the Failed task?

Or, if the session ID is created outside and passed in to the workflow, is it possible to share this ID to all the tasks?

[image: state machine]

Answer (score 0):

Specify `ResultPath` property in the error catcher. By default it is `$`, which means that output of a failed Parallel State will be only error info. However, if you set `ResultPath` to, for example, `$.error_info` then you will preserve state and error data will be accessible under `error_info` property.

For more details, you may be interested in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html (Error Handling).